# error glm, NA/NaN/Inf in 'y

Tags: r, na, glm

I am trying to fit a GLM model to my data. The data (`rope_complete`) looks like this:

```
      rope.X...Sound rope.directional.change rope.Time.of.the.shark.in.the.video
1           5_min_blank                       5              23
2           Snorkeling                        11             37
3                 Fish1                       1              17
4                 Fish1                       6              46
5                 Diving                      6              37
```

Now i wanted to check if I have `NA` values:

```
table(is.na(rope_complete))
```

and saw that I have none:

```
FALSE  : 3225
```

Now I did my GLM:

```
directional_turn_fit<-glm(rope_complete$rope.directional.change~
                        rope_complete$rope.X...Sound
                      +offset(
          log(rope_complete$rope.Time.of.the.shark.in.the.video))
          , family = poisson)
```

but i still get the same error:

```
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  :             
Na/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

I am a little bit lost, because i have no idea what i should do now. I know my data is Poisson distributed.

Comment: Do you have zeros in your offset? i.e. what is `any(rope_complete$rope.Time.of.the.shark.in.the.video == 0)` ?

Comment: Think of `is.na(Inf)` is FALSE. What object is **rope_complete**? If it is a dataframe you have to examine each column ... use sapply() or lapply().

Comment: hey, 
i tried now to find 0´s and it says true so i definitely have some. Is that a problem? 
And how do i solve it?

And yes it is a data frame.
How do i do with is.na(INF)?

Thanks already for your help!

Comment: I tried again, but i can't delete the 0´s because they are part of my data. 
I don't think i have INF´s because i checked my data set.

Comment: Just trying to complete the question here. When you model this as a poisson distribution and put "rope.Time.of.the.shark.in.the.video" as the offset, you're effectively modeling the counts of "rope.directional.change" that occur per amount of time that the shark is in the video. This construct doesn't work when the shark is never in the video, so those data would need to be discarded.